# How to retrieve data from Instagram that is absent in their API

Tags: python, android, api, instagram, instagram-api

I am currently trying write a code to retrieve an Instagram users email. This is not feasible through their API. The manual way to do it is to go on a mobile phone (not feasible from desktop) and if they have a business account there will be an option called Email which will then open Gmail and give you the email. Is there a way for me to run a bot through the Instagram App to retrieve that information and export it back to my computer? Time is not an issue for how quickly the data is retrieved, I could run the code overnight, but I was curious as to how/if this was feasible.
Thank you!

Comment: You need to be authorized to view contact data.

Comment: If you're on Mac, you can use AppleScritp, first to fool Instragam and let it beleives it runs on Mobile (Safari->Dev->User Agent) then you'll have access at "mobile" features.

Comment: Thanks, so I can't be authorized to view contact data and regarding the Safari dev, that's good but i need to actually run the Instagram app, email doesn't show up on Instagram on Safari on iPhone.